# Nervous stimuli and neurotransmitters and impacts

Tags: central-nervous-system, peripheral-nervous-system

As far my knowledge, in body parts generally **acetacholine ** is the neurotransmitter. Which is responsible for most nervous impulses.

Consider a body part, say, foot. Only one  nerve reaches here. When ant bites there, the impulse of pain and irritation moves from there ;

Secondly, when some soothing agent comes there the impulse of comfortness moves from there

Now, neurotransmitter is the same, nerve is the same, but different impacts are observed.

My teacher said that the impulse moves to different parts of the brain.

But how are the impacts really understood, analysed and sent to different regions ( as entrance of all stimuli enter through the same brain stem,)

In short,

My question is that how does our brain analyses two different stimuli when neurotransmitter is the same, nerve is the same and enter the brain through the same brain stem. They must be going to different regions of the brain but how is that decided

Comment: Please see [this related Q&A](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/27699/does-the-nervous-system-have-routers). Although that question's focus is on the motor system, the answer also provides adequate coverage for the sensory system. If you still don't understand something after reading the linked Q&A, please edit your question accordingly in order to let us know what more specific details you need help with.

Comment: Would you be kind to tell that What specifications you require?

Comment: Did you read the linked question? Does it cover your question? Or is there something more you need to know?

Comment: This related question talks about the action of peripheral nervous system. By presenting two models. I am not talking about that. My question is that how does our brain analyses two different stimuli (like i have written in the post), when neurotransmitter is the same, nerve is the same and enter the brain through the same brain stem. They must be going to different regions of the brain but how is that decided?